# Chartjs legend not visible even after setting to true

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am reletavely new to chartJS, and I was looking for a way to display labels on my doughnut chart. I tried to set the visibility of the legend to true in options, but it still did not work.

```
var data = [{
        data: [successfulBuildsCount, failureBuildsCount],
        labels: ["Successes", "Failures"],
        backgroundColor: [
          "green",
          "red"
        ],
        borderColor: "#fff"
      }];

      var options = {
        legend: { display: true, },
        title: {
          display: true,
        },

        plugins: {
          datalabels: {
            formatter: (value, ctx) => {

              let sum = 0;
              let dataArr = ctx.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
              dataArr.map(data => {
                sum += data;
              });
              let percentage = (value * 100 / sum).toFixed(2) + "%";
              return percentage;


            },
            color: '#fff',
          }
        }
      };


      var ctx = document.getElementById("chartContainer");
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
          datasets: data
        },
        options: options
      });
```

Comment: Legend options should be under `plugins` (check the [doughnut sample](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/other-charts/doughnut.html)). However, the legend is probably visible, but when you're saying "labels on my doughnut", you mean datalabels, not the legend. You should post a full running example so we can see if you did import and register the datalabels plugin - instead of registration you may also use the `plugins: [ChartDataLabels],` property on the configuration object, see [Registration](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#registration)

Answer (score 0):

The legend should show by default. If it is not showing I assume you are using treeshaking and not importing and registering the legend plugin like this:

```js
import { Chart, Legend } from 'chart.js';

Chart.register(Legend);
```

Or you can make sure you don't miss anything by letting chart.js import and register everything:

```js
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
```